# SwiftUI how to change background color for TextField on Light theme (appearance)?

Tags: swift, background, swiftui

The issue is the work of `.background()` modificator work on different themes.

Absolutely the same code have different effect on both themes:

[image]

[image]

is there issue on my side or this is a bug of swiftUI ?

```
        TextField("Any text", text: $anyText)
            .background(Color.red)
```

Comment: you have to choose systemRed instead of red if you want to have a suitable red background on dark mode. Or you have to have two different colours and load them on light and dark themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue will be fixed in case of using "Mac Catalyst project" instead of any other type of project.

There is absent such behaviour and it works perfectly on both themes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Human Interface Guidelines section for Dark Mode reads:

> Use the system-provided label colors for labels. The primary, secondary, tertiary, and quaternary label colors adapt automatically to light and dark appearances. For related guidance, see Typography.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/dark-mode/

Try setting a .secondary()  color for your text

Comment: `Value of type "TextField<Text>" has no member "secondary"`